# What is the best way to store data from my repository?

Tags: database, api, file-upload, metadata, system-design

I'm building a website with a "repository" where the user can download and upload several files of different sizes. My idea is to use my database with metadata to store information (extension, some tags and the path where it is stored). And then the user can access this data or search the application. My problem is that I don't know the best way to store it, I thought of using google drive, S3 and dropbox through API's. But I would like to know other ways to make this possible. I know it's a complex subject, but I would like you to tell me where to study.

Answer (score 0):

for storing metadata you can use mongodb sync with file id and for storing large file you can use google drive API (let me know if you intrested ) or some kind of file hosting.